# CardLayout with MouseListener not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener, cardlayout

I am dealing with `CardLayout`. The `JPanel` I added as a contentpane to my `JFrame` has a  `CardLayout`, and I want to swap between different panes. I have a working pane with buttons and five other image panes for the tutorial that are to be displayed only if a certain boolean value is true. I mean, every time this boolean is set true, five swaps should be done using `next()` method. My problem is that, after the first swap, the screen becomes blank. why does this happen?

Second question. I am using a `MouseListener` to swap, but I would like the program to do it automatically after some time. I tried to use `Thread.sleep(5000)`, but I get a black screen.

This is my code, where card is a class variable in order to use it in the `Mouselistener`, `parent` is the working panel, already created, and `ImagePanel` is a class to create tutorialPanels, which adds to them the `MouseListener` below. Also, `rootPane` is a class pane.

```
card = new CardLayout();
    rootPane = new JPanel(card);
    this.getContentPane().add(rootPane);
    //create panels to add
    ImagePanel inputTutorial = new ImagePanel("backgroundIn.png");
    ImagePanel numericTutorial = new ImagePanel("backgroundNum");
    ImagePanel outputTutorial = new ImagePanel("backgroundOut");
    ImagePanel commandTutorial = new ImagePanel("backgroundCom");
    ImagePanel errorTutorial = new ImagePanel("backgroundErr");
    ImagePanel finalTutorial = new ImagePanel("backgroundFinal");
    //add  the panels
    rootPane.add(parent);
    rootPane.add(inputTutorial);
    rootPane.add(numericTutorial);
    rootPane.add(outputTutorial);
    rootPane.add(commandTutorial);
    rootPane.add(errorTutorial);
    rootPane.add(finalTutorial);
    //set rootPane content panel
    this.getContentPane().add(rootPane);
    //if the boolean is true
    if (firstTime == true) {
        card.next(rootPane);
        //other swaps done by mouselisteners
    }
```

This is the mouselistener:

```
//mouse click listener
private class MouseActionListener implements MouseListener {
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            card.next(rootPane);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

I know that the listener is executed because I checked it.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: An actually [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: _"I tried to use Thread.sleep(5000) but I get black screen"_ - Don't use `Thread.sleep()`. See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "but I would like the program to do it automatically after some time. I tried to use Thread.sleep(5000)"

Don't use Thread.sleep. Instead use a `javax.swing.Timer`. You can learn more at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Here's a simple example, using some of your app format.

[image]

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SlideShow {

    public SlideShow() {
        final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel mainPanel = createMainPanel(layout);

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                layout.next(mainPanel);
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel(CardLayout layout) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
        panel.add(new ImagePanel("mario.png"));
        panel.add(new ImagePanel("bowser.png"));
        panel.add(new ImagePanel("luigi.png"));
        panel.add(new ImagePanel("koopa.png"));
        panel.add(new ImagePanel("princess.png"));
        return panel;
    }

    private class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        BufferedImage image;

        public ImagePanel(String fileName) {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/marioblobs/" + fileName));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) 
                    : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SlideShow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, really useful help for the timer, but I still get blank screen at the second swap. Any suggestions? @peeskillet

Comment: Looking at your posted code, only the first `ImagePanel` has a .png file extension passed to it. That _may_ be the problem.

Comment: Oh no! I can't believe I've made such a stupid mistake... That's why I got blank screen! Thank you for your precious help!